# Calling $scope in custom filter (angular)

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using this angular filter to filter out objects in an array whose `localteam_id` properties match a value that is held in `$scope.whichMyteam`. This works fine.

**VIEW**

```
<div ng-repeat="fixture in getFixtures | filter: {localteam_id: whichMyteam} ">
```

I want to extend the filter however, to include a section criterion: so it will, in effect, be:

```
<div ng-repeat="fixture in getFixtures | filter: {localteam_id: whichMyteam && visitorteam_id: whichMyteam} ">
```

...but a) this doesn't work, and b) even if it did, it's getting a little cumbersome and seems that it would justify making a custom filter.

So, I tried to make one. The problem I ran into is I need to reference the `$scope.whichMyteam` value in the filter, but it seems the filter module can't accept/understand `$scope`. This is crucial for the filter to work in my instance, so I'm not sure how to resolve this.

**My filter so far looks like this:**

```
app.filter('myFixtures', function() {

      return function(input) {
        angular.forEach(input, function(o) {
          output = [];
          if (o.localteam_id === $scope.whichMyteam) {
            output.push(o);
          }
          return output;
      })
    };

  });
```

The above is a simplified version which only attempts to match one property (just did this to test it and reduce the number of moving parts). When I call it in the view though...

```
<div ng-repeat="fixture in getFixtures | myFixtures">
```

...it doesn't work. Console logs '$scope is not defined'.

---

UPDATE: I tried this, still not working!

### FILTER

```
var myFilters = angular.module('myFilters', [])

    myFilters.filter('myFixtures', function(whichMyteam) {

      return function(input) {

        angular.forEach(input, function(o) {

          output = [];

          if (o.localteam_id === whichMyteam) {
            output.push(o);
          }
          return output;

      })

    }

  });
```

### VIEW

```
  <div ng-repeat="fixture in getFixtures | myFixtures(whichMyteam)">
```

---

Console is logging a syntax error (I think...)

```
angular.js:13236 Error: [$parse:syntax]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about having your filter function return a function.

```
app.filter('myFixtures', function() {
  return function(input, whichMyteam) {
    output = [];
    angular.forEach(input, function(o) {
      if (o.localteam_id === whichMyteam) {
        output.push(o);
      }
    })
    return output;
  };
});
```

Then call the filter function passing in your variable

```
<div ng-repeat='fixture in getFixtures | myFixtures:whichMyteam'>
```

--- example

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .filter('otherFilter', otherFilter)
  .controller('controller', controller);


controller.$inject = ['$scope'];

function controller($scope) {
  $scope.things = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  $scope.modVal = 2;
  console.log('controller');
  $scope.myFilter = function(x) {
    return function(y) {
     return (y % x) === 0; 
    }
  };
}

function otherFilter() {
  return function(y, x) {
    var out = [];
    angular.forEach(y, function(val) {
      if ((val % x) === 0) {
        out.push(val)
      }
    });
    return out;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='controller'>
  <div ng-repeat='thing in things | filter:myFilter(modVal)'>
    {{ thing }}
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div ng-repeat='thing in things | otherFilter:modVal'>
    {{ thing }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here:
1. How to pass a param, html:

```
<div ng-repeat="fixture in getFixtures | myFixtures:whichMyteam">
```

js:

```
    myFilters.filter('myFixtures', function() {

      return function(input, whichMyteam) {
...
```

2. Do not place return statement inside forEach -- it does not make what you think;)

So finally your filter is:

```
myFilters.filter('myFixtures', function() {

 return function(input, whichMyteam) {

    output = [];

    angular.forEach(input, function(o) {
      if (o.localteam_id === whichMyteam) {
        output.push(o);
      }
    })

    return output;
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/0XFfI8hIdCaJ19gJRYr2?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to custom filters - and this has solved my problem. I have ONE more question: If I want to check against two properties, how do I write that? Currently I have:         `angular.forEach(input, function(o) {

          if ( o.localteam_id === whichMyteam ) {
            output.push(o);
          }

          if ( o.visitorteam_id === whichMyteam ) {
            output.push(o);
          }` ...this works, but I'd rather not have to write two 'if' statements if possible. I tried it with `o.localteam_id === whichMyteam && o.visitorteam_id === whichMyteam` but no luck.